# Install Google analytics components into Flash CC?

Tags: flash, components, flash-cc

How can you, or is it even possible to install the google analytics components into Flash CC?

Answer (score 0):

A short answer for a short question
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/flashTrackingSetupFlash?hl=es

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't cover Flash CC.

Comment: Oops, didnt even notice! sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from the downloads section of this link :
https://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/